# How can I determine about a command, that which package provides it, using the command line?

Tags: apt

Let's say, I have a command for which I want to know the source code. For example: unity-webapps-runner. I know `which unity-webapps-runner` tells me where to find, but how to find out with `apt-cache` that which package installed the binary, so I can run `apt-get source <pkg-name>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command,

```
dpkg -S $(which unity-webapps-runner)
```

The output of the above command shows

```
unity-webapps-service: /usr/bin/unity-webapps-runner
```

So `unity-webapps-runner` was belongs to `unity-webapps-service` package.

Get the source of `unity-webapps-service` package by running the below command,

```
apt-get source unity-webapps-service
```

Answer (score 2):

`dpkg` has this option. Read same question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/146875/command-to-find-the-source-package-of-a-binary)

Do this:

```
bash:$ dpkg -S unity-webapps-runner
unity-webapps-service: /usr/bin/unity-webapps-runner
```

Then if you want more information use `apt-cache`

```
bash:$ apt-cache showpkg unity-webapps-service
```